# Location of 32 bit binaries on x86_64 system. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, 64-bit, 32-bit

I would like to have both x86_64 and i386 `docker` binaries installed. Where is the location of docker:i386 binary? I've checked `/usr/bin/docker` but it shows usage of x86_64 libraries as below

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe665f9000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f19d88de000)
libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f19d86d4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f19d830a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f19d8afb000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f19d8106000)
```

Both docker versions were installed through apt-get install.

Comment: I think you can use the binary from the package you install as the last. The path for the binary are the same in amd64 and i386 architecture. If you want to have two separate package (binary) you could rebuild the docker package with rest requested binaries and specifying them the custom install path (in build process).

Comment: So default behaviour of packages is overwrite? I mean when i install docker:i386 after docker, will it overwrite my previous binary?

Comment: Another way is to manualy download, extract package and copy content to another location, isn't it?

Comment: I think yes. As you can see here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/docker.io/filelist and here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/i386/docker.io/filelist the path(s) for both architectures are the same. I think you are able to check that in the easy way, as it is not a cricital package :) Install the package for the amd64 architecture and check the binary: `file /usr/bin/docker` then, install for the i386 and do the same.

Comment: Download, extract and copy content to the another location not will be easy (and I thin it will be not possible) because the packages have dynamically linked libraries, so the better way will be install the package for you main architecture and then try to port (rebuild) the package for the other arch and point it the another install path.